# Android Image View does not start from top

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have two linear layouts placed side by side. The right side layout contains an image strip. The problem is the image does not start from top, there is unwanted bottom margin appearing as well, creating unnecessary scrolling. 
Best would be if there is no unnecessary scrolling at all. There are more buttons at the left side. Right side image may be clipped.

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewCaption"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="This is my Application"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnOne"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                android:text="Button One"
                android:textSize="@dimen/home_sub_caption_height" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                android:text="Button Two"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnThree"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                android:text="Button Three"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewLogo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/qutub" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: This is my app's screenshot]

Comment: change the revelation images

Comment: 250*250 take that size

Comment: If scrolling is not necessary, just use `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

in the ImageView use
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

instead of 
 android:layout_height="match_parent"

I guess it would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need scroll then remove the **ScrollView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewCaption"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="This is my Application"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:text="Button One" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:text="Button Two"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnThree"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:text="Button Three"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewLogo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/profile" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewCaption"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="This is my Application"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:text="Button One"
           />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:text="Button Two"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnThree"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:text="Button Three"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewLogo"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/profile" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute in `ImageView`

> `android:scaleType="fitStart"`

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I do this, the image is top aligned, but bottom margin is doubled. Lots of gap below the image, lots of unnecessary scrolling.

Comment: can you show me the sample layout in the animated version?

Answer (score 0):

Try it set `Imageview` `layout_gravity="top"` and `layout_height="wrap_content"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewCaption"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="This is my Application"
            android:textSize="40sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:text="Button One"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:text="Button Two"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnThree"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:text="Button Three"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewLogo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/qutub"
            android:layout_gravity="top"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```